# Fifo Method in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, fifo

I have to implement something similar of a FIFO method in SQL. The thing is that I have points issued in different months and at the same time I have points exchanged in other date. The thing is that I have to know how many months ago were issued the points until the exchange. So the first points to be exchanged are the olders, but if 200 points were issued the 30/06/2014, and 100 points were issued the 31/07/2014, and the 31/08/2014 I exchanged 250 points. 200 points have 2 months of development (the 200 of June) and 50 points have one month of development (50 of 100 issued in July). How can I code this?

I leave some table to better understanding!

Thanks

```
Date of issue   Number of account   Issued points
30-abr                    1            300
31-may                    1             50
30-jun                    1            100
30-jun                    2            100
30-jun                    3            120
31-may                    4             20
30-jun                    4            200



Date of exchange    Number of account   Exchanged points
30-jun                     1                  250
31-jul                     1                  200
31-jul                     3                   30
30-jun                     4                   30
31-jul                     2                   10
30-jun                     3                   30
31-ago                     4                   10
```

And the final table I need is.

```
Issue date  Months after issue  Exchanged points
30-abr           2,00               250,00
30-abr           3,00                50,00
31-may           2,00                50,00
31-may           1,00                20,00
30-jun           1,00               100,00
30-jun           1,00                30,00
30-jun           0,00                10,00
30-jun           1,00                10,00
30-jun           0,00                30,00
30-jun           2,00                10,00
```

**Edit**: Adding example to clarify the problem with account 1:

Points issued in 3 different months:

```
Date of issue   Points
30-apr          300
31-may           50
30-jun          100
```

These are exchanged in 2 occasions:

```
Date of exchange    Points
30-jun              250
31-jul              200
```

Since the exchange is happening from points issued in different months, the result should be 4 actions, so that the earliest points are used first:

```
Date of exchange    Date of issue   Points    Months
30-jun              30-apr          250       2
31-jul              30-apr           50       3
31-jul              31-may           50       2
31-jul              30-jun          100       1
```

Comment: Are you using `MySQL` or `SQL Server`? Pick one.

Comment: Sorry, I am using SQL Server

Comment: It looks like you want to **Group By AcctNum** (num of Acct) in your final table but there's no **AcctNum** field. Otherwise rows with **Jun 30** and **1 month** would have the **points** summed.

Comment: Hannover Fist, I only want to Group by AcctNum to exchange the points. The exchange in July of the #1 AcctNum is 50 for the first issue (in April), 50 for the second issue (in May), and 100 for the third and last issue (in June). In my final table I don't want to group by AcctNum.

Comment: The description is quite bad, but the idea seems to be to calculate age how long ago the points were issued when they are exchanged separating each of the case where the exchanged points are made from different issued batches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I played around with this and this SQL returns the correct result. Somehow I feel like it might have bugs in it, but at least that's somewhere to start (or the totally wrong way to go):

```
;with I as (
  select 
    date,
    points,
    account,
    isnull((select sum(points) from issue i2 
       where i2.account = i1.account and i2.date < i1.date),0) as Cumulative
  from
    issue i1
),
E as (
  select 
    date,
    points,
    account,
    isnull((select sum(points) from Exchange e2 
       where e2.account = e1.account and e2.date < e1.date),0) as Cumulative
  from
    Exchange e1
),
X as ( 
  select
  I.Account,
  I.Date as IDate, I.Points as IPoints, I.Cumulative as ICumulative,
  E.Date as EDate, E.Points as EPoints, E.Cumulative as ECumulative
  from I 
  join E on I.account = E.account 
        and I.Points + I.Cumulative > E.Cumulative
        and E.Cumulative + E.Points > I.Cumulative
)

select 
  Account, IDate, datediff(month, IDate, EDate) as After,
  case when EPoints + ECumulative < IPoints + ICumulative 
      then EPoints 
      else IPoints + ICumulative - ECumulative end
  - case when ICumulative > ECumulative 
      then (ICumulative - ECumulative) 
      else 0 end as Points
from X
order by IDate, EDate
```

The first 2 CTEs (I and E) calculate running total for the points, the 3rd (X) gathers the needed rows based on what's been issued and exchanged. The formula for calculating the final Points column was just trial and error, so I'm not 100% sure it's accurate in all cases :)

You can try this in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/91bde9/1)

Comment: I need one adaptation for the first table because there are negative issues  points and I need the net table considerating the negatives points as debit of the first time of issue.

Comment: E.g:

Date of issue   Number of account   Issued points
30-abr                    1            300
31-may                  1             50
30-jun                    1            100
30-jun                    1            -50
30-abr                    2            200
31-may                  2             60

I want this table

Date of issue   Number of account   Issued points
30-abr                    1            250
31-may                  1             50
30-jun                    1            100
30-abr                    2            200
31-may                  2             60